# New Session ID when Using Isomorphic Fetch

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I have an unexpected behavior when using isomorphic-fetch vs. request-promise related to Express sessions (and Express session ID in particular):

As part of the troubleshooting process, I implemented two methods in `client.js` for calling endpoints in `server.js`: 1) isomorphic-fetch, and 2) request-promise.

Client.js

```
// Method 1: isomorphic-fetch
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');

fetch('http://localhost:3000', {
  credentials: 'same-origin',
})
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.status);
});

fetch('http://localhost:3000', {
  credentials: 'same-origin',
})
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.status);
});

// Method 2: request-promise
var rp = require('request-promise').defaults({
 jar: true
});

function requestPage() {
  return rp('http://localhost:3000/');
}
requestPage()
  .then(console.dir)
  .then(requestPage)
  .then(console.dir)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
app.use(require('morgan')('dev'));
var session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);

app.use(session({
  name: 'server-session-cookie-id',
  secret: 'my express secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  store: new FileStore(),
  cookie: {
    secure: false
  }
}));

app.get('/', function initViewsCount(req, res, next) {
console.log('req.session.id = ' + req.session.id);
  if (typeof req.session.views === 'undefined') {
    req.session.views = 1;
    return res.end('Welcome to the file session demo. Refresh page!');
  }
  return next();
});

app.get('/', function incrementViewsCount(req, res, next) {
  console.assert(typeof req.session.views === 'number',
  'missing views count in the session', req.session);
  req.session.views++;
  return next();
})

app.use(function printSession(req, res, next) {
  console.log('req.session', req.session);
  return next();
});

app.get('/', function sendPageWithCounter(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.write('<p>views: ' + req.session.views + '</p>\n');
  res.end();
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

When I execute `node client.js`, here is the output of the server:

```
req.session.id = deWKCvqcyGiAvVSUvHv2Db7sjvE7xN1E
req.session.id = MxLHWjbMMvV4GRfPSf6sQ12XvauiJJot
req.session.id = A3KTLMdBopQ7pAfcTsJhnzzdokdA7hGI
GET / 200 1.407 ms - -
GET / 200 7.625 ms - -
GET / 200 0.728 ms - -
req.session.id = A3KTLMdBopQ7pAfcTsJhnzzdokdA7hGI
req.session Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: false },
  views: 2,
  __lastAccess: 1517449125197 }
GET / 200 6.902 ms - -
```

I confirmed that method 2 (request-promise) successfully persists the session on the server.  In other words, session `A3KTLMdBopQ7pAfcTsJhnzzdokdA7hGI` is associated with this method.

However, as observed from the output, method 1 (isomorphic-fetch) generates two separate sessions on the server.

**Question**: Why does isomorphic-fetch create two separate sessions on the server?

**Troubleshooting performed**:

1. I replaced `localhost` with `127.0.0.1`, but this did not change the behavior.
2. I replaced `same-origin` with `include`, but this did not change the behavior.

**Environment:**

- node v6.10.3
- isomorphic-fetch 2.2.1
- request-promise 4.2.2

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?  I'm having a similar issue.  Seems like the cookie and original request data is lost when fetch runs on the server.  Since there is no cookie data, express creates a new session.